# Dot matrix printing module for Node.js/Electron?

Tags: node.js, npm, printing, electron, dot-matrix

I have this kind of a big Java swing application containing 70,000+ lines of code that i want to migrate to Electron. I have a critical requirement for printing with Epson dot matrix printers (ESC/P2). To be more specific Epson LQ-310. Currently I'm using [RTextPrinter](http://www.java4less.com/textprinter/index.html) for this task which works perfectly but i can't seem to find a Javascript alternative for this. I found [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-thermal-printer) and [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/escpos) but pretty sure those won't work with LQ-310.

Comment: just out of curiosity and to help potential answerers, what makes you "pretty sure those won't work with LQ-310"?

Comment: Because i tried them with a LQ-300+ II which has the same interface.